# D3 map visible area coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

here is my simple code for d3 scalable map:

```
  winWidth = $(window).width();
  winHeight = $(window).height();

  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .translate([0, 0])
      .scale(winWidth / 2 / Math.PI);

  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 50])
      .on("zoom", manageMap);

  path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + winWidth + " " + winHeight)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + winWidth / 2 + "," + winHeight / 2 + ")")
      .call(zoom);

  g = svg.append("g");

  d3.json("world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
    g.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries))
        .attr("class", "land")
        .attr("d", path);

    g.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "boundary")
        .attr("d", path);
  });

function manageMap() {

  var t = d3.event.translate,
      s = d3.event.scale;

  t[0] = Math.min(winWidth / 2 * (s - 1), Math.max(winWidth / 2 * (1 - s), t[0]));
  t[1] = Math.min(winHeight / 2 * (s - 1) + 230 * s, Math.max(winHeight / 2 * (1 - s) - 230 * s, t[1]));

  zoom.translate(t);
  g.style("stroke-width", 1/s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");
  svg.select("g").selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[1]; })
      .attr("r", 11/s);

}
```

Is there any simple way to have current visible area coordinates, when map is scaled and translated? I'm already try to project translation of map, but just got some strange numbers.

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to calculate it directly from the transformation, i.e. min to (min + dimensions/scale). This will give you screen coordinates which you can translate into map coordinates with the projection.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff sorry, but I really confused with this stuff, can you point me more? What is min?

Comment: Min would be the smallest shown coordinate, i.e. the translation (`t` in your code).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I try this in enf of mapManage:
`t[0] = t[0] + winWidth/s;
t[1] = t[1] + winHeight/s;
console.log(projection.invert(t));`

But output is, for example, `[272.20426947980627, -81.79887775042842]`. What is wrong?

Comment: Those coordinates by themselves don't mean anything to me. Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff http://bl.ocks.org/lenyapugachev/8518523 and a lot of thanks for helping me

Comment: Hmmm, this is actually more complex than I thought because you're using the SVG transform to zoom/translate and not the projection. It would be easier if you did everything with the projection (see [example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206489)) -- in particular you should be able to calculate the view extent like I've described then.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it. I've also put it up on http://bl.ocks.org/sfinktah/1d38c8a268d893d769ed

Even if you have found **your** solution, this may be useful for future googlers.

```
function getScreenBounds() {
  return [getPoint(0,0), getPoint()];
}

function getPoint(x,y) {
  if (x == null) x = winWidth;
  if (y == null) y = winHeight;
  var container = g.node();
  var svg = container.ownerSVGElement || container;
  var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = x, point.y = y;
  point = point.matrixTransform(container.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  return formatLocation(projection.invert([point.x, point.y]), zoom.scale());
}

function formatLocation(p, k) {
  var format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
  return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + "°S" : format(p[1]) + "°N") + " "
       + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + "°W" : format(p[0]) + "°E");
}
```